# Precision resta javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un software de contabilidad y tengo graves problemas con los cálculos de los decimales.

He aqui un ejemplo:
si hago la resta 3.00 - 2.70 me da 0.29 y no 0.30 como deberia

```js
console.log(3.00-2.70);
```

Comment: Te aconsejo que evites los números con coma flotante cuando trabajes con dinero, usa enteros o usa [una librería que te permita trabajar con ellos sin perder precisión](https://www.google.es/search?q=BigDecimal+js&oq=BigDecimal+js&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4324j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al principio creí que con la función `Math.round()` solucionarías el problema, pero al probarla, me di cuenta que no aguanta decimales. Por eso, al seguir googleando, me encontré con esta solución, que pareció ser efectiva: habría que probarla con muchos valores para saber si siempre retorna el valor deseado.

```js
console.log(parseFloat(3.00-2.70).toFixed(2));
```

La sugerencia de solución la encontré en [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12830454/2956233)
. Allí podrás leer todo el análisis que hacen los usuarios sobre los posibles fallos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta.
He encontrado una librería que me ha ayudado a corregir este problema [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js)